# How to remove a service that keeps the system from booting?

Tags: centos, systemd, services

I created a service that starts a script using exec, because it works on upstart. On systemd it keeps the system from booting, because it waits for my script to end, but since it is a webserver, it won't end until stopped. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can't you just use Type=forking in the [Service] section?

Comment: Please post your service file. As @MariusMatutiae said, you need to change (or add) the `Type=` directive in the `[Install]` section; but more details are required to say what value do you actually need.

Comment: I would love to, but the file is only at the computer that won't boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### updated (specific) answer

You can easily block a service from being started directly (like `disable`ing it) or being started by any other systemd units by adding a parameter to the kernel command line:

```
systemd.mask=name.service
```

### original (general) answer

As MariusMatutiae mentioned you have to modify the unit file (or disable it). In order to do that you can either boot a different Linux (it is a good idea to have a small additional Linux installed for such purposes; you may boot from CD/DVD or USB stick, too) or you boot this Linux with boot options which prevent running into this problem.

From http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/

**Booting into Rescue or Emergency Targets**

To boot directly into rescue target add `systemd.unit=rescue.target` or just `1` to the kernel command line. This target is useful if the problem occurs somewhere after the basic system is brought up, during the starting of "normal" services. If this is the case, you should be able to disable the bad service from here. If the rescue target will not boot either, the more minimal emergency target might.

To boot directly into emergency shell add `systemd.unit=emergency.target` or `emergency` to the kernel command line. Note that in the emergency shell you will have to remount the root filesystem read-write by yourself before editing any files:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

If not even the emergency target works, you can boot directly into a shell with `init=/bin/sh`.

Comment: It did the trick, I burned the centOS iso on a pendrive and used rescue mode to delete the service.

Comment: That trick of passing `init=/bin/bash` is invaluable.  To think, all these years I was making boot media to rescue such systems, each time.

Comment: @fuzzyTew That is indeed a very useful kernel parameter. But it turned out that there is a much better one for this specific problem. See the updated answer.